# How to enlarge the size of a textbox I am looking for in a XML file, using the pdfquery library, Python

Tags: python, xml, pdf, automation

I would like to ask you for help in my issue.
Idea - Automating an order taking procedure.
Source - A pdf generated file from a customer, technically identical each time.
Tool - Python with the pdfquery library

I have a box in an XML file, which pdfquery creates with the coordinates of the "PO" number.
Technically the files are automaticaly generated by the customer, so they "are identical".
But using the "hardocded" coordinates - on the second file no values are read by Python.
It turned out that the boxes can differ slightly in size.

The four values describing the box are (x0), (y0),  (x1), and (y1).
These values define the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners of the bounding box.

In my case the box in the second file had coordinates differing by less than 1 pixel, and I have written some code where i expand the box where the "PO" value should be.
But I receive no values in return. Are you able to advise why?

My code:

```
`import pdfquery`


#read the PDF
# pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery('PO 4507595428 - Bakker Tilburg - 19.07.2023.pdf')
pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery('4507568636 MCC UK to Dema.PDF')
pdf.load()


#convert the pdf to XML
pdf.tree.write('benelux.xml', pretty_print = True)
pdf.load()

"""
The four values in this case are 335.0 (x0), 798.63 (y0), 390.85 (x1), and 808.63 (y1). 
These values define the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners of the bounding box.


# access the data using coordinates
# po = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("335.25, 798.63, 390.85, 808.63")').text() # < from 2.pdf****
po = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("335.0, 798.63, 390.6, 808.63")').text() # < from 1.pdf
print("PO: ", po)

################################################# poniezj te kombinacje z PO :
# Original coordinates of the box
x0 = 335.25
y0 = 798.63
x1 = 390.85
y1 = 808.63

pixel_adjustment = 5  # Increasing the box size by 5 pixels

# Adjusting the coordinates of the bounding box
enlarged_x0 = x0 - pixel_adjustment
enlarged_y0 = y0 + pixel_adjustment
enlarged_x1 = x1 + pixel_adjustment
enlarged_y1 = y1 - pixel_adjustment

# Querying the elements using the enlarged bounding box
elements = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("{},{},{},{}")'.format(enlarged_x0, enlarged_y0, enlarged_x1, enlarged_y1))
print("The PO after expanding the textbox: ", elements)
```

Comment: Could you share a demo PDF, which shows the problem?